# Configure Tomcat for multiple remote debug connection?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, ide

I successfully configured my Tomcat for remote debugging from either Eclipse/IntelliJ. But there is only one remote connection at a time, other connections will fail to connect. Is there any way to increase the number of connections?

Here is my configuration in `catalina.sh`:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Comment: You want to attach two debuggers at a time? What would that accomplish? I doubt it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible for two simultaneous connections (processes, people) to debug the same JVM.

Comment: You mean if I have two containers (e.g. tomcat and jboss) running on the same jvm, I cannot debug two either even I configured separate ports?

Comment: I don't know if you can get two servers running on the same JVM, but yes you won't be able to. Please post if you find a way though...